# Decomposition group $G_p$ equals the absolute Galois group of the p-adics

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am reading some lecture notes and came across the fact that the group $G_p \leq G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ (where $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the absolute Galois Group of the rationals and $G_p$ is the decomposition group corresponding to the rational prime $p$) satisfies

$G_p \cong G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$

where $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ is the absolute Galois Group of the $p$-adics.

I cannot figure out why this is true. I have a vague intuition that if an element of $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ fixes $p$ it should somehow fix the $p$-adic distance, but I am not sure how to formalize this thought.

Any help or reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the beginning of Cassels-Frohlich? Briefly: let $L/\mathbb{Q}$ be finite Galois, fix a prime $\mathfrak{p} \subset O_L$ above $p$. Then any automorphism $\sigma$ of $L$ preserving $\mathfrak{p}$ preserves the $\mathfrak{p}$-adic valuation: therefore, it induces an automorphism of the completion $L_{\mathfrak{p}}$ (and it is $\mathbb{Q}_p$-linear). This constructs a map from the decomposition group of $L/\mathbb{Q}$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ to $Gal(L_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathbb{Q}_p)$. You can check that this map is bijective; then let $L$ grow and watch what happens to this bijection.

Comment: @Aphelli That for $K/\Bbb{Q}$ finite Galois and $p\in \mathfrak{p}\subset O_K$, $D_\mathfrak{p} = Gal(K_\mathfrak{p}/\Bbb{Q}_p)$ is relatively obvious, but showing that $D_\mathfrak{p} = Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p/\Bbb{Q}_p)$ for $K=\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ is much less elementary. We'd need to show that $Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p/\Bbb{Q}_p)$ acts continuously on $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p$, and Krasner lemma to show that $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ is dense in $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p$.

Comment: @reuns: I don’t understand what you mean by “continuity of the action”. I think the finite argument above still shows an isomorphism into the Galois group of $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$, where $K$ is the extension generated by algebraic numbers? I had certainly overlooked that we still needed to prove that $K=\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ (and there’s no escaping Krasner for this, although I think “much less elementary” is a bit strong).

Comment: Thank you both for your comments! Would you mind giving a bit more details how to get from the finite case to the $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$? Thank you!

Comment: Please note that the notion of "*the* decomposition group" of $p$ in $G_{\mathbf Q}$ is ambiguous: it depends on a choice of prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ over $p$ in the ring of all algebraic integers $\overline{\mathbf Z}$.  Changing the prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ will change the decomposition group by conjugation, so a "decomposition group at $p$" in $G_{\mathbf Q}$ is well-defined only up to conjugation.

Comment: @Aphelli the relevant part of Cassels-Fröhlich is I.10 Proposition 3